# Why does this inverted amplifier circuit behave so differently from the simulation?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

I have built the following unity-gain inverting amplifier with an LM358 op-amp. I expect 3 volts at the output which the simulation confirms. However, when I build the circuit in real life, my noninverting input is at ground (expected), my inverting input is at -0.7 volts and my output is at -0.6 volts. I've verified my input is at about -3V and my supply rail is sitting at 11.9 volts.

The frustrating thing is, I swear it was working yesterday.
I swapped out the op amp for a different one and get the same problem.

[image: schematic]

[image: circuit in real life]

Comment: Your schematic does not show a connection between your 12V power supply and ground. Is the 12V power supply connected to the same ground as your -3V power supply on your breadboard? Your image does not show that detail.

Comment: what is the op-amp's negative supply voltage?

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry I messed up the schematic. The 12V supply and -3V supply are connected to the same ground. i.e. the op amp negative supply pin is grounded.

Comment: Your 12V supply seems to "float" with respect to ground. You could change that by using two 6V supplies in series and connect their mid-point to ground. Besides, it is a good idea to use e.g. 100nF caps between Vcc+ and GND and Vcc- and GND, close to the op amp pins.

Comment: Are you sure protoboard matches schematic?  5 wires on schematic vs what looks like 4 on protoboard.

Answer (score 0):

You need a ground on the power supply. For example, +/-6V.

If you ground the (-) side of the 12V supply you may experience phase reversal unless you add a Schottky diode from the inverting input to ground.